# NSArray initWithContentsOfFile returns nil

Tags: objective-c, ios5, xcode4, xcode4.2

I'm trying to read a plist file into `NSArray` using `initWithContentsOfFile` as described [here](http://mobiledevelopertips.com/data-file-management/reading-a-plist-into-an-nsarray.html)

My code looks like this

```
    NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
    NSString *plistPath = [bundle pathForResource:
                           @"routes" ofType:@"plist" ];
    routes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:plistPath ];
    NSLog:(@"contents of myArray %@", routes);
```

`routes.plist` has a perfectly simple structure of array and 2 string values inside

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Root</key>
    <array>
        <string>1</string>
        <string>2</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

[image: This is how it looks in xcode]

Everything seems to be fine. `plistPath` initializes with correct value, which means file is copied to the bundle and can be readed. But `routes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:plistPath ];` returns `0x0` value. I think this is equal to `nil`

What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Actually your plist is a dictionary.

Change this:

```
<dict>
    <key>Root</key>
    <array>
        <string>1</string>
        <string>2</string>
    </array>
</dict>
```

to this:

```
<array>
    <string>1</string>
    <string>2</string>
</array>
```

Comment: Man, you're right. But in Xcode visual editor I've choosen Array type! See the screenshot I've added. Is it an Xcode4 bug?

Comment: Nope. You have an array object with a key named "Root" (which gives away that your plist is a "`NSDictionary`").  You could add additional objects at that level with different key names.

Comment: But there is no choice, Xcode creates dict by default and you can not change it in visual editor. Only by editing plist as a source file. But ok, now I know about it. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, if you want a root array, you have to do it right in the XML.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to do something like this:

```
NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
NSString *plistPath = [bundle pathForResource:
                       @"routes" ofType:@"plist"];

NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
NSArray *routes = [dictionary objectForKey:@"Root"];
```